# Robot framework - Trying to read data in edit mode, but its not fetching the text, instead its fetching "--Select--"

Tags: robotframework, robot, keyword-driven

After clicking on Edit, a new page appears. I want to read a few data from that opened page. I used `GET` Value with locator to fetch **id** value.

**Id has 4 values**

1. New
2. Open
3. In progress
4. Close

where `--Select--` is field watermark or placeholder

After clicking on edit, I could see the value of id in UI is 'In progress'

```
${Id}=Get Value//label[@for='Id']/following-sibling::div/div/div/div[1]
Log To Consoleid ${Id}
```

**console output :-**

```
id -- Select --
```

I intend to get the correct value **'In progress'** from UI. However it is not fetching the correct value, its showing  `--Select--`.

**Element in UI:-**

```
<li class="grid__col-x required" style="display: flex;"> ==$0
::before
<label for="Id">Id</label>   
<div class="css-18asa text-input react-select--is-disabled">
    <div class="css-g9sas react-select__control react-select__control--is-disabled">
         <div class="css-asas react-select__value-container react-select__value-container--has-value">
              <div class="css-212wew react-select__single-value react-select__single-value--is-disabled">In Progress</div>
              <div class="css-rsyb7x">
```

Comment: Use get text , get value gets the information from that value attribute i

Comment: I tried with both Get text and Get value... It did not fetch the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Value, returns the content of the 'value' attribute.

Use Get Text instead

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Input Text
    Open Browser    file:///D:/testout.html    chrome
    Wait Until Page Contains Element        xpath://*[contains(text(),"In Progress")]
    ${Id}=    Get Text    //*[contains(text(),"In Progress")]
    Log To Console    ${Id}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I tried this also. It returned --Select--, whereas in UI, it was 'In progress'

Comment: @sneha for get Text you got select ? try using wait before fetching the data

Comment: @see the updated answer

Comment: @sneha make sure you are using correct locator

Comment: I used Wait until element is visible, it was fetching the elements properly where drop down is not there.

Comment: For drop down, I used Wait Until Page Contains Element. Its working now..Thanks PD.

Comment: @sneha could you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near my answer